# multiple sub recyclerview and listview

Tags: java, android

I want to implement multiple list in my android app, the list contains cardview

```
1. Recyclerview (cardview)

 1.1 listview (cardview)

 1.1.1 listview (cardview)
```

how can I achieve this ? thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Aditya Please explain more ,

may be in your app listview add inner recyclerview ? if i'm right

first xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

/>

2nd Rccyclerview Adapter items

Add listview in Recyclerview Adapter

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_5"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/size_2"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/size_5"
    >
<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```